# Sharepoint 2010 visual web part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Please provide me a link or help :

I want to make my visualwebpart to communicate with other webparts like (Provider and Consumer)

I am thinking can I make my VisualWebPart which has a ascx file which is drived from UserControl, can I make it a Provider or a Consumer.

Note: I am adding these webparts on Sharepoint 2010 webpartpage.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765.aspx

Comment: Thats is WebPart, I want to make a "VisualWebPart".

Answer (score 0):

just to update you guys that I wanted to do like this

http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-connectable-web-parts-using.html

May be it will help someone else suffering the same question :)

Cheers,
RHM